# align 2 images of different dimension in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, positioning

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (imga) at (0, 0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}};

\node[right = 10 of imga, inner sep=0pt] (imgb)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-b}};

\node[below = 5 of imga, inner sep=0pt] (imgc)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-c}};

\node[below = 5 of imgb, inner sep=0pt] (imge)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (imgd) at ($(imgc)!0.5!(imge)$)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code draws a `tikzpicture` like:

[image]

Image A and image C are of different dimension. Is there a way to align image A and image C horizontally so that the left margin of A and left margin of B are at the same line?

Hopefully, `[on grid]` doesn't have to be changed as I rely on it for other nodes' positioning.

Comment: What about `\node[below = 5 of imga.west, inner sep=0pt, anchor=west] (imgc)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-c}};`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With set anchor to west and make node distanco also from west:

```
\node[below = 5 of imga.west, anchor=west] (imgc)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-c}};
```

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style ={inner sep=0pt},
                    on grid]
\node (imga) {\includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\node[right = 10 of imga] (imgb)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-b}};

\node[below = 5 of imga.west, anchor=west] (imgc)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-c}};  % <---
\node[below = 5 of imgb, inner sep=0pt] (imge)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (imgd) at ($(imgc)!0.5!(imge)$)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]